# How to use Git with a one-line file

Tags: git

I'm trying to use Git to version a config file for a quadcopter. The config file is unfortunately all one line and it's impossible to see individual settings changes.

Here's an example: https://github.com/pgallen90/cleanflight-settings/commit/868e9ef2fefd689ed6d2430378cf66cd825e0771

Any way to change Git settings or tools to make it so I can see individual settings changes within the file?

Comment: That looks like it's just JSON - are you sure it *has* to be on one line? Why not just format the JSON, at which point it'll be a lot easier to see the differences.

Comment: Thanks -- that makes sense, but it needs to be on one line to send to the device. Would this be a good use for Git hooks to generate another file on commit that is a prettified version of the JSON?

Comment: Changes: "board_align_yaw":180, Well the temporary solution is just copy paste the old file in notepad++ and then replace all <,> with <,\n>. do the same for the new file as well. and Then use any merging software to see the difference between both files. Well I know this is not the thing you are looking for. :-)

Comment: you can try `git diff --word-diff-regex=.`

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using a pre-commit git hook to convert to formatted JSON.

**The pre-commit git hook file is described in the README.md:** https://github.com/pgallen90/cleanflight-settings

**Here's an example of what the changes look like:** https://github.com/pgallen90/cleanflight-settings/commit/c2ae6ca31271744a0ce7f99f7482614ae74ca826#diff-c319b959789a85bd81f368dc70ad63e1